# Why does System.DateTime.Now work when the application is ran on my computer but does not work when i start the application over workgroup?

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine, share, workgroup

When the application is run on the computer that it is stored on it loads time, however, when it is loaded over workgroup, on another computer it does not load time (even though everything else works as it should).

I have made an application, for Windows using Unity and C#, that requires the ability to load today's date from the system, and it works when the application is run on the computer where it is stored (the application does not require installation), however, when I try to run it over workgroup from another computer it does not load the time.
I have tested everything else in the application, and the only function that seems to be malfunctioning is the DateTime.Now function. I also tried replacing it with DateTime.Today, System.DateTime.Now, and a few other variations, but all have yielded no success.

```
public class TestTodayDate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text text;

    void Start()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        string[] day = today.ToString("d").Split('/');
        text.text = $"{day[1]}.{day[0]}.{day[2]}";
    }
}
```

This is the expected result and the one I get when running the application locally.

[image: Expected result]

This is the result I got when I ren it on 2 different computers over workgroup.

[image: Actual result]

Comment: Are you sure that you are executing the exact same code in both places?  I ask because of the format string you have which contains periods and array references. 
 Since you are not performing any check on the result of your `split` code, if the array has any length less than 3 this code should throw an exception.

Comment: Protip: *never* make assumptions about date formats!

Comment: thank you for the help, once I just printed it in its raw form I saw that it returns the date and time in a different format (on my PC it's month/day/year and so on, and on the other two its day.month.year)

Comment: I edited out your link to the code image. Please don't post code in image format, always post the code directly in the question itself (I realize you posted some of the code, I just took what was in the image and moved it into the post and I am adding this comment as an attempt to be helpful)

Comment: When you use the format string `d` with a `DateTime` object it's format is culturally dependent.  You can check the docs for [DateTime.ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) to see a good example of the differences.

Comment: in other words, I have to use ToString and in the brackets add a specific format as to make it consistent.

Comment: Yes, if you want a specific format.  In your case, you could specify the format to produce the one with the dots and then you don't have to mess with splitting and then reforming it, specify your desired format and use it. On the other hand, I still have the question of why you didn't see an exception. The code you posted will throw an exception if the date is formatted differently than your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"d"` format string uses the system-level configured short date string format. *Individuals can change this format on their system as they see fit.* Therefore, if you need to rely on the result looking a certain way, you should not use the `"d"` format string.

Instead, you may be tempted to do this:

```
void Start()
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    string[] day = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Split('/');
    text.text = $"{day[1]}.{day[0]}.{day[2]}";
}
```

But this is also not quite correct. In .Net date format strings, the `/` character has special meaning, where it stands in place of the system date separator. Again, this value might be different from what you expect based on the cultural or custom settings present in the OS.

What you should really do is this:

```
void Start()
{
    text.text = DateTime.Now.ToString("d.M.yyyy");
}
```

This will always provide the expected value (though I had to guess on the day format, whether or not you expect to ever see a leading `0` at the beginning of the month), and it will save you some memory allocations creating the array and intermediate string.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved the problem I was having